# What happens when you "Offer Blood" in exchange for items?

Tags: curse-of-the-dead-gods

All shops offer the ability to pay in either gold or blood. What paying in gold does is obvious, but I'm not sure what paying in blood does. I assumed it meant you sacrificed life in exchange for the item, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

[image: Curse of the Dead Gods Relic Shop]

How do you pay for items when you choose the "Offer Blood" option?

Comment: It actually took a few runs until I figured this out, because the game doesn't explain it to you, and it isn't immediately obvious. The name really makes it sound like you'll be paying with HP instead, and I initially assumed the corruption amount listed just happened whenever you bought the item. It wasn't until a couple failed google searches, and paying close attention to each of my meters when I purchased stuff, that I actually figured it out. All that's to say I figure others will find this information useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Offer Blood" means you gain corruption in exchange for the item. The corruption you gain is listed below the item, right next to the gold (circled in the below figure).

[image: Curse of the Dead Gods Relic Shop]

If the corruption you'd gain would result in you having 100 corruption, then you'll gain a new curse (when you leave the room), your corruption will be reset to 0, and then any excess will be added back. So in the below situation I'd gain a curse, and then my new corruption value would be 50.

It's also worth noting that it appears **you can still buy items with blood even if you already have five curses (the maximum).** I'm not 100% sure on this, but I was still able to purchase an expensive item with blood even though I was only 20 corruption away from unlocking the final curse. This just maxed my corruption out at 100, and unlocked the final curse (see below). I didn't have a chance to purchase anything else with blood before the run was over, so I can't be 100% certain of this, but it seems very likely. If true, then it would appear there's no  downside to purchasing items with blood once you're already at five curses.

[image]